# Failed to emit precompiled header error in Xcode 12.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode12

I update my Xcode from 10 to 12.4, after updating getting this error.

```
failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/ji.../K0IWW.pch' for bridging header '/Users/j....ng-Header.h'
```

I am using a bridge file in my application.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please [edit] your question add some more information, including a [example]. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

**Check the header path & .pch file location**,

- this issue happens always majorly developed codes from old versions
  from Xcode, based on location path is in manual. Either change your
  location path for error files to current(correct) location or make
  SRCRoot to it. So it can detect the file automatically.